# Failed to upload iphone build

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have tried to upload iPhone build , first time it show me success message but when i open iTunes Connect to upload new screenshots and add some data I got the following error

[image]

So I tried to upload the build again using xcode and using application loader 3.0 but I keep getting this error also

[image]

and the iTunes connect is still showing the first error

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must increase build no to upload again. 
Once you upload is finished successfully, build appears in iTunesConnect Test Flight tab with status **Processing**. Processing takes 15-30 minutes. Once processing is done you go to the **App Store** tab and select that build, select the build and save.

[image]

**Note:** If build disappears after **Processing** from the Test Flight, it means there is something wrong with your build, account admin and agent of iTunesConnect should have received an email with details about the issues(s). Fix all the issues and upload another build and don't forget to increase the build number.

Comment: the problem that the + icon beside build never appear

Comment: make sure status (in let panel) is **Prepare for Submission** and version no matches with build version no.

Comment: Ok will try and let you know